# Algebraic surfaces with no deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Is very well known that the only algebraic curve which admits no deformations is the  projective line.

> **Q.** What are "rigid" smooth algebraic surfaces? Is there a sensible classification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several different notions of "rigidity" (local rigidity, global rigidity, infinitesimal rigidity, étale rigidity and strong rigidity) and it is possible to provide examples for each of them.

This topic is discussed in the paper by I. Bauer and F. Catanese *[On rigid compact complex surfaces and manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08128)*, you can have a look at it for more details and references to the literature.

Comment: Thank you. I actually meant  local rigidity (apparently the weakest).

Comment: It looks like this paper has an answer to my question, in a sense that a complete classification seems out of reach.